Multiple conformance to same protocol with different associated types
Good day, sir or madam!
I have a family of very similar protocols, and, naturally, would like to avoid code duplication by moving the common part to a parent like this:
public protocol EntityProcessor<T> {
    associatedtype T: Entity
    
    func insert(_ item: T) throws
    func delete(_ item: T) throws
    func update(_ item: T) throws    
}

public protocol ExpenseService: EntityProcessor<Expense> { }
public protocol BudgetService: EntityProcessor<Budget> { }

And then use them as follows:
public class DataStoreImplementation: ExpenseService & BudgetService {
    func insert(_ item: Expense) throws { }
    func insert(_ item: Budget) throws { }
    // ...
}

However, the compiler can't figure it out as it can't have multiple different values for T in a conforming type.
Is there a proper way to implement this idea with similar brevity?
Update:
Here is a piece of the intended implementation for context:
// Services & Entities are in separate packages
import Services
import Model

// A framework of choice; might be changed to CoreData / SwiftData / Firestore etc.
import RealmSwift

class Expense: Object {
    
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var date: Date
    @Persisted var amount: Decimal128    
    @Persisted var category: ExpCategory?
}

class ExpCategory: Object { ... }

public actor RealmDataStore {   
    var realm: Realm
    // ...
}

extension RealmDataStore: ExpenseService {

    public func insert(_ item: Model.Expense) throws {
        try realm.write {
            realm.create(Expense.self, value: [
                "id": item.id,
                "date": item.date,
                "amount": item.amount
            ])
            // TODO: add category
        }
    }

    //...
}

extension RealmDataStore: BudgetService { ... }

The implementation is in a separate package, and neither the services (ExpenseService etc.) nor the entities (Expense etc.) know anything about it.

Look's like it's problem for swift compiler now. Just doesn't use common ancestor-protocol. You can use macro instead: macro will generate required interface for protocols.

What do you gain by having an insert function for each entity type?

@Cy-4AH Indeed, macro seems to be the very thing I was looking for, thanks! Haven't used them much yet (except for the default ones) - but looks like the time has finally come

@JoakimDanielson I use Realm under the hood, and for each entity there's a certain mapping to apply a read/write operation. I figured that the most straight-forward place to map it either way would be the respective method (pretty much as it is in the official doc, only with a single struct parameter instead of several fields https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/device-sdks/sdk/swift/use-realm-with-actors/#write-to-an-actor-isolated-realm)

You could have a protocol that defines how to convert/map from an to your realm types and have methods that are generic over that protocol in DataStoreImplementation

You can only conform to a given protocol one way. You cannot conform to the same protocol with different associated types. So the answer is you can't do that.
That said, I'm not quite clear how the above construct would actually improve code duplication. Are you sure you don't really want a insert(_ item: some DataType) method instead? Do you really need so many nearly-identical protocols? For example, I would expect this system to look like this:
protocol Entity {}

struct Expense: Entity {}
struct Budget: Entity {}

public class DataStoreImplementation {
    func insert(_ item: some Entity) throws { }
    func delete(_ item: some Entity) throws { }
    func update(_ item: some Entity) throws { }  
}


As I remark in the comments, it is very difficult to abstract your persistence engine without losing much of why you chose the persistence engine. You're going to wind up doing a lot of things twice if you don't want "Realm-ness" to leak into your whole program. But even so, it's worth discussing what these designs look like. There are surprisingly few protocols required (just one). (I'll warn you, I haven't even looked at Realm in years, and do not remember its syntax; consider this implementation "abstract" since that's what you were talking about.)
First, models can just be models. They could be Object classes, but they could just be structs:
// Models just exist

struct Expense {
    let id: ObjectId
    var date: Date
    var amount: Decimal
}

Notice how ObjectId snuck in, though. It's a bit challenging to not expose a consistent identifier type.
So models are just models. Data stores are just data stores.
public actor RealmDataStore {
    var realm: Realm = Realm()
}

But we can also build a bridge between them:
protocol RealmStorable {
    static var realmType: Object.Type { get }
    var realmDictionary: [String:Any] { get }
}

And with that kind of bridge, we can teach RealmDataStore to do things on unknown types:
extension RealmDataStore {
    func insert(_ item: some RealmStorable) throws {
        try realm.write {
            realm.create(type(of: item).realmType, value: item.realmDictionary)
        }
    }
}

And then we can teach Expense to be one of those types:
extension Expense: RealmStorable {
    // You could just use this in your whole program, but if you want to
    // hide "Realm-ness" then you're going to have to duplicate stuff.
    class RealmExpense: Object {
        @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: ObjectId
        @Persisted var date: Date
        @Persisted var amount: Decimal128
        @Persisted var category: ExpCategory?
    }

    static var realmType: Object.Type { RealmExpense.self }
    var realmDictionary: [String : Any] {
        [
            "id": id,
            "date": date,
            "amount": amount
        ]
    }
}

And that's it. No need for interlocking protocols.
And of course you don't have to do all this wrapping. You can implement realmType for every Object:
extension Object {
    static var realmType: Object.Type { Self.self }
}

You'd still have to implement realmDictionary, but you had to write that somewhere no matter what. But the point is that it goes on the Entity, not on the store.

Thanks Rob! Yeah I was thinking about it myself (e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/modelcontext/insert(_:) ), but didn't come up with an elegant way to map the incoming some item to a dictionary + respective persistent type (which is required by Realm that I use under the hood). Actually, I could put the mapping dict, type and whatnot into Entity extensions- but, to my understanding, it would still requite using some switch-case, which I wanted to avoid if possible (DataStoreImplementation & Realm are in a separate package, which Entities know nothing about)

Generally the mapping would be done by the type as a requirement of the Entity protocol. So you'd call entity.realmObject or whatever you want to call it. You can add the Entity protocol via retroactive conformance in its own file (even in a different module); there's no need for Expense to know it's an Entity at all.

Your idea of just swapping out the persistence engine, however, is extremely unlikely to work. I've seen people try to build this for years. Choosing Realm is big choice. It defines how you structure things. It injects things like Object and ObjectId that you cannot easily ignore. Switching to SwiftData isn't just "swap some types." It changes how you query things, and how you build your relationships. By the time you make these things lowest-common-denominator, you strip them of their usefulness, leaving just their challenges.

Actually I've started with SwiftData (as it's a pet I use to play with new frameworks & ideas), and used it throughout the app as is. But it turned out to be so.. let's call it half-baked, that I decided to switch to something else. And, recollecting Robert Martin's advice to totally abstract the DB layer, I decided to finally give this idea a shot in a controlled environment :) Hence the original question. Should this venture prove fruitful - not sure yet myself - I'll be happy to share the resulting code with you. I do expect some extra work, but hope to keep it at a reasonable level

I don't see much of a challenge in ObjectId though, as in most cases I'd expect it to easily map into string and vice versa (thus use String in the original Expense instead). Furthermore, making Expense: Identifiable and considering it's id as Expense.ID (instead of String / UUID / whatever we choose to be the specific type) across the app, it should be fairly easy to substitute it with whatever exotic Hashable we need to reflect the underlying db-specific ObjectId.

Regarding the other concerns - this approach does strip away great deal of benefits, but as my main area of interest is mobile dev, many (if not most) of the applications require fairly little. That is, some 5-15 types and about as many parametrised queries (mb with an extra luxury - some kind of change listeners for the queries to hook the view models on). Under this assumption, implementing the abstraction layer might worth one's while, as it doesn't seem to be that costly. Whether this holds true in practice remains to be seen :)

"totally abstract the DB layer." The confusion here is that SwiftData/Realm/CoreData are not really "the DB layer." They are object-graph persistence systems. This is very different from a "database" even if they happen to often be implemented on top of a database. They are not just simple CRUD systems.
